# Unable to attach new click event handlers on HTML element using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Why is the on click event on anchor not triggering while manually clicking in a debug session from VS Code?

Broadly here is my goal:

- Go to linkedin.com using Puppeteer in **headful** Chrome
- Login
- Go to linkedin.com/jobs
- Attach a click event handler for all the links on the page
- Pause the node.js execution after attaching the event handlers
- Click the links manually with my mouse to observe this new event handler in action

In code, this is what I got

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/');
    await login(page);
    await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/');
    await attachLinks(page);
    await page.screenshot({ path: "bla" })
    browser.close();
};

async function attachLinks(page) {
    const bodyHandle = await page.$('body');
    await page.evaluate( (body, numLinks=3) => {
        let anchors = Array.from( body.querySelectorAll("a") ).
            filter( (e, i) => i < numLinks );
        for(let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            let a = anchors[i];
            console.log(`Binding for ${a.href}`);

            // This event does not trigger!!!!!
            a.addEventListener("click", e => { 
                console.log("some one clicked the link");
                e.preventDefault(); 
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                return false; 
            });
        };
    }, bodyHandle);
    await bodyHandle.dispose();
}

main();
```

Then using VS Code and node.js debugging support, I put a breakpoint on line `await page.screenshot({ path: "bla" })` after the `onclick` event for `<a>` tags is attached. In the browser that opens (as headless is set to false), while the code is waiting to be resumed, I clicked the `<a>` tags in the `<body>` with my mouse, expecting to see "some one clicked the link" in the headful debug Chrome browser's console. But I dont see a logs either in the browser or in VS Code's Debug console. Am I missing something here?

Comment: where you expect the console to be rendered ?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking at the browser's DevTools console for these logs? Or the debug console in VSCode?

Comment: Yeah, in the headful browser's console, as `attachLinks` function adds onClick event handler to them. I double checked the VS Code Debug Console as well. Nothing there too.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not actually clicking the anchor tag. You've attached an event to it "click" and defined what will happen when we will click it, but you're not actually clicking it. Just add `a.click()` like

```
       // This event will now trigger
        a.addEventListener("click", e => { 
            console.log("some one clicked the link");
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
            return false; 
        });

        a.click();
```

see the name `addEventListener`, you're attaching an event listener, not actually clicking it

Comment: Thanks Tripti. But my goal is to click manually (not via code) during the debug session as explained in the question after the code :)

Comment: @Nitin sorry for that. Try putting `await page.waitFor(2*1000);` after `await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/');` line

Comment: You can alternatively use `await page.waitForNavigation();` also in place of `waitFor()`. The whole idea is to wait slighlty for the page to load before firing off another event

Comment: Thanks for all the great tips Tripti. My problem is not being able to stop the browser, in which case `waitFor` variants would have helped. Using VS Code's debugger I paused the browser after attaching the links by placing a breakpoint at `await page.screenshot({ path: "bla" })`. While it is waiting to resume, I manually click the links on the page but I dont see the console statements from click event handlers hinting that they are not attached

Comment: Yes ok, but my suggestion still remains the same. Why I am saying this is by not pausing after `goto` using `waitFor`, the variable `bodyHandle` remains null, because of which links are not being attached.
So I'll just put up a last comment, did you use waitFor in your code and then debug it in VS code? If yes is it still giving the same results? If again yes, then I'll stop here since I won't be able to help in this regard :) @Nitin

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying, I changed goto to `await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});` but still dont see any console logs on clicking the links. Thanks for help @tripti